# Trouble trusting local HTTPs certificate in ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, ssl-certificate

I am following an online tutorial to create an ASP.NET Core Web application. I followed everything but had trouble with trusting the local HTTPS certificate.

When I first run the application, I got an error saying:

> the access control list (acl) structure is invalid

I tried googling this error but couldn't find anything related to my ASP.NET application, after cleaning the solution I didn't get this error any longer.

But I was unable to run my application in browser using `HTTPS` as it always says:
"This site is not secure"

I tried to trust certificate using CMD using this command:

`dotnet dev-certs https --trust`

It should show me a prompt to trust the certificate but it says

> there was an error trusting the HTTPS developer certificate

and the application runs in an unsafe mode on the browser.

Can someone please help me run my application with HTTPS on my local environment? Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: just wondering, are you an administrator user?

Comment: @ZeeshanAdil yes, I am an administrator

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This seems to be a bug in ASP.NET Core 2.1:

what you need to do is go move your added certificates from your certificate manager.

go to start menu > Type "Win + R" type "certlm.msc", this will open your certificate manager.

go to Personal/Certificates

you will find a certificate named "*localhost* there.

Move that to "Trusted Root Certification Authorities/Certificates"

run the project again, and it should work.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Here's for mac users: https://support.apple.com/guide/keychain-access/change-the-trust-settings-of-a-certificate-kyca11871/mac

Answer (score 11):

I had this issue in .net 6, solve it with help of [this comment](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/26458#issuecomment-701385682).

```
dotnet dev-certs https --clean
dotnet dev-certs https --trust
```

Answer (score 6):

If the other answers don't work, trying completely closing all Edge windows.

What can happen is that Edge doesn't recognize the new certificate until you restart it.

Comment: Underrated solution, this needs to be done after making any of the other fixes.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem in .NET 5. Running the command gave me the same error. After a few iterations I figured it out finally...

I was trying to create certificates manually through certlm.msc (local computer) but apparently the certificate should be created in certmgr.msc (current user). This is the place where the certificate gets saved when you run the command
`dotnet dev-certs https --trust`.

1. Windows + R and type certlm.msc
2. Go to Personal -> Certificates and export the localhost certificate with the same key (asks for password)
3. Go to Trusted Root Certification Authorities -> Certificates and right-click to click on Import
4. Browse and select the exported certificate
5. Place all certificates in the following store is selected and click on Browse again
6. Mark the checkbox: Show physical stores
7. Click on Trusted Root Certification Authorities and press on Local Computer
8. Finish everything

Answer (score 1):

I have tried all the suggestions but eventually, The below solution worked for me.

1. Uninstall IIS Express via Add Remove Program
2. Run command: dotnet dev-certs https --clean
3. Re-install IIS Express by downloading it from the Microsoft website
4. Run the Asp.Net application from Visual Studio
5. Visual studio will prompt for generating a certificate, click yes.
   In my case, it generated the certificate but failed to add the certificate to the trusted root with an error 'Access Denied'
6. Windows + R and type mmc
7. File > Add Snap-In
8. Select Certificates and click add
9. Select the 'Computer account' option and click finish, then click Ok.
10. Then expand the certificates(Local Computer) > Personal > Certificates
11. You will find a local host certificate with the friendly name 'ISS Express Development Certificate'
12. Select the certificate then cut and paste it into Trusted Root Certification Authorities -> Certificates