# Getting error "Failed trusting the certificate" while running my Blazor App in Visual Studio 2022

Tags: c#, blazor, visual-studio-2022

I installed Visual Studio 2022 and created a Blazor web assembly project. When I started the application, Visual Studio 2022 prompted to trust the self signed certificate that ASP.NET Core has generated. Please refer below screen shot:

[image]

After I clicked "Yes" then it generated error "Failed trusting the certificate" as shown in below screen shot:

[image]

Please help me to fix the error. I have also tried following command but it did not fix my issue:

```
dotnet dev-certs https --trust
```

**Note:** Visual Studio 2019 is also installed on my machine i.e. currently I am having both VS2019 and VS2022 installed on my machine.

Comment: did you have valid self signed certs? run 'dotnet dev-certs https -c' plz

Comment: It is already mentioned in question.

Comment: I had this and cleaning certificate helped me: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70257639/1154773

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Finally I was able to fix the problem and I am mentioning the steps which fixed my problem. It can be beneficial for someone:

**Step 1:** Open "Manage user certificates" by searching in Windows search bar and delete localhost certificate from "Personal -> Certificate":
[image]

**Step 2:** Now locate and delete localhost certificate from the "Trusted Root Certification Authorities -> Certificate":
[image]

**Step 3:** Open "Manage computer certificates" and delete localhost from both "Personal" and "Trusted Root Certification Authorities":
[image]

**Step 4:** Start Visual Studio in Administrative mode and run your application. Click Yes if prompted to trust the self-signed certificate:
[image]

**Step 5:** Now open "Manage user certificates" again and after selecting localhost click on Export:
[image]

**Step 6:** Click on Next button:
[image]

**Step 7:** Select "DER encoded binary X.509(.CER)" and click next:
[image]

**Step 8:** Save the file to Desktop with the name "localhost.cer"
[image]

**Step 9:** Now double click on the localhost.cer file that you just saved in Step 8 to install the certificate.
[image]

**Step 10:** Install the certificate for the "Local Machine":
[image]

**Step 11:** Select "Place all certificates in the following store" option and browse the certificate store by clicking on the browse button. Then select "Trusted Root Certification Authorities"
[image]

**Step 12:** Repeat Steps 9 to 11 but this time install it for "Current User" and install it in "Trusted Publishers" certificate store.
[image]

**Step 13:** Restart the Visual Studio and re-run your application and hope it will fix your problem.

Comment: This didn't completely solve my problem. When I enter "dotnet dev-certs https --trust" I no longer get an error message, but when I start the server the certificate is still displayed as invalid in the browser. Do you know how to fix this error or what is causing it?

Answer (score 2):

Resolving this issue seems to be identical as to similar already posted question:
[Visual Studio 2017 gives 'Adding the Certificate to The Trusted Root Certificates store failed with the following Errror'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47413183/visual-studio-2017-gives-adding-the-certificate-to-the-trusted-root-certificate)

I would recommend to add the localhost certificate to Trusted Rood Certificates.

Answer (score 0):

in cmd type dotnet --info
if you can not see the correct version of net core installed then you need to install it again.
in some cases you need to install dot net core 32 bit to resolve the problem.