# ERROR: Adding the certificate to the trusted root certificates store failed Visual Studio 2022

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2022

I'm using Visual Studio 2022.

When I open an ASP.NET Core project and I click play, I got those messages:

[image]

[image]

I tried to run these commands:

1. `dotnet dev-certs https --clean`
2. `dotnet dev-certs https --trust`

but when I ran the second command, I got this error:

[image]
and with more details:
[image]

I tried to go to `MMC.exe` and more/delete the localhost from personal -> certificates, and from "Trusted root certification authorities".

The bottom line nothing works I'm trying few days to fix it, please help me out.

Thanks

Comment: One possibility is your system requires a signed certificate and the certificate is not signed.

Comment: [Step 4](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72445729/17034), don't forget to elevate.

Answer (score 0):

This issue can usually be fixed by following the following steps:

1. Open the control panel and search for "manage user certificates" in the upper right corner

[image]

2. Open "manage user certificates" and expand "Personal", click "Personal"

[image]

3. If you find multiple "localhost" certificates, you need to delete them all.
4. Run the project and regenerate the certificate

Comment: thanks for the response but as I said in the post, I already tried all you've said and I still have the same problem..